# GeoReference XYZ point cloud

Tags: georeferencing, lidar, point-cloud

I am looking for help. I have done a little bit of geo-registration of images with QGIS. But now, I have been handed some LIDAR data in [PCD format](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php) (basically x,y,z), But it is not geo-referenced.

I have looked at: [Georeferencing LAS files in geographic coordinates (lat/lon) or in cartesian (projected) ones?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132015/how-to-georeference-las-files), but I do not have LAS data, and that article talks nothing about what would work for a GUI to do GeoReferencing, as QGIS provides.

I know the exact area and have obtained a GeoTiff from Google Earth. The entire region is only about 30 acres. So I am assuming that a simple linear transform of the values will be sufficient. But I am was wondering if any GUI tools could help with the conversion (at least getting the ground control points to line up and the linear formula). I have used QGIS to do this for unknown raster data, but this is the first time I have been asked to do this for point cloud.

My simple research has found a ideas, which likely won't work, but maybe someone can tell me what does work:

I have found an interesting free tool called [cloud compare](http://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=Align) which if I understand the [demos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjiJBqckv90), I might be able to use (it looks like it needs two point clouds, but I could convert the GeoTiff with FME to a point cloud). I do not have ESRI available. Is Cloud Compare able to do this? How hard would it be?

If we want to put out $400 perhaps the Blue Marble folks can do this with their LIDAR plug in: http://forum.globalmapperforum.com/discussion/7444/georeference-static-lidar-data , does anyone recommend that?

I have also see this in the Matlab Vision Toolkit: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcregrigid.html#bux42c5

Comment: Thanks for editing. I don't think this question is opinion-based; the first question seems objective to me. I'd support reopening it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDAL](http://pdal.io) can do this for you, but not automatically. You need to use something to compute your transformation matrix and then apply the transformation matrix with PDAL's [filters.transformation](http://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.transformation.html) filter. Once you have your transformation matrix, you can use the transformation in a pipeline as shown in the [example](http://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.transformation.html#example).

[OSGeo4W64](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) is a binary distribution for Windows that contains this software, or you can build it yourself using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) on OSX. There are RPMs for Linux too at [this location](http://www.pdal.io/download.html#rpms), but building on Linux is straight forward. See the [compilation doc](http://www.pdal.io/compilation/unix.html) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I can also do the transform in FME (using the Point cloud expression evaluator : http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop_Help.htm#../Subsystems/FME_Transformers/Content/Transformers/pointcloudexpressionevaluator.htm ) The  trick is coming up with the transform. I am having the best luck with the Matlab Viision Toolkit Stitching and Registration functions: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/3-d-point-cloud-registration-and-stitching.html